# Retrieve data from Shared Preference Object then display it on a ListView

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I am saving data from the user using shared preference object then copy that data into a HashMap object. After data has been copied to the Hasmap Object, I use an Arraylist object to display all my data in the ListView.

When I test using only Textview instead of ListView, it works. I can display data, but it only displays one record (key/value pair). I want to use ListView so that I can display all the data stored in my shared preference object.

Below is the class that copies data from shared preference object to a HashMap then uses an arrraylist to display it on a ListView:

```
public class DisplayMyTestsActivity extends Activity {

    String STName;    
    TextView STNameTextView, STValueTextView;
    ListView STListView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.displaymytests);

        //Use SharedPreferences to save the key/value pairs
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("STData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //save "special test name" in String 'testName'
        String testName = sharedPref.getString("specialTestName", STName);

        //save special test Value in String 'testValue'
       boolean testValue = sharedPref.getBoolean("specialTestValue", false);
       //save the boolean value in a String so that it can be displayed on an edit text
       String testValueStr = String.valueOf(testValue);

       //here I tested if I can display my data on a textView instead of a ListView and it works
       // Display the Name of the Special Test on a TextView 
       STNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.STNameView1);
       STNameTextView.setText(testName);

       //Display the Value (positive or negative) of the Special Test on a TextView
       STValueTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.STValueView1);
       STValueTextView.setText(testValueStr);

       //to edit the data or add data inside my file "STData"
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

       //Define a HashMap object
       Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

       //Store key/value pair data from shared pref in HashMap object
       for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
       {
          editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
          editor.commit();
       }

       //Pass hashmap object "map" to adapter
       //MyAdapter constructor creates an ArrayList then adds all the data in map to the ArrayList
       //The object "adapter" is now an arraylist that contains all the hashmap data (I created a seperate adapter class)
      MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(map);

      //Point to the listView where data to be displayed - in layout file (displaymytests)
      STListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ST_ListView);

      //Populate the listView with the data from The ArrayList ('adapter')
      STListView.setAdapter(adapter);

     }

 }
```

Here is my adapter class:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final ArrayList mData;

    public MyAdapter(Map<String, String> map) {
        mData = new ArrayList();
        mData.addAll(map.entrySet());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<String, String> getItem(int position) {
        return (Map.Entry) mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO implement you own logic with ID
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {
            result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_adapter_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            result = convertView;
        }

        Map.Entry<String, String> item = getItem(position);

        // TODO replace findViewById by ViewHolder
        ((TextView) result.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(item.getKey());
        ((TextView) result.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(item.getValue());

        return result;
    }
}
```

And here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.06">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="STName"
            android:id="@+id/STNameView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="STValue"
            android:id="@+id/STValueView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.94">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="387dp"
            android:id="@+id/ST_ListView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I modified my code as follow, but still gives me the error:   "Incompatible error at this line "map = sharedPref.getAll();""

```
    //Define a HashMap object
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Store key/value pair data from shared pref in HashMap object
    map = sharedPref.getAll();
    //Retrieve the the keys with keySet() and the key/value mappings with entrySet()
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet())
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        editor.commit();
    }
```

FYI, getAll() returns an object of type Map(String, ?), but mine is Map(String, String) b/c I need to pass it to **MyAdapter** and should be of type Map(String, String)

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're creating an empty `Map` and using that for the adapter.  So that loop on `map.entrySet()` never executes, and you have an empty list.

`SharedPreferences` has a method called `getAll()` that returns your preferences as a `Map`.  You might just be able to use that.

Comment: I modified my code as follow, but still gives me the error: